# OpenShift apache modules

Tags: apache, openshift

How do you find out on OpenShift which apache modules are loaded?

I tried following the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation), and can see the compiled in modules by running `/usr/sbin/httpd -l`. However if I try to run `/usr/sbin/httpd -M`, or an equivalent command, I get an error: "Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Permission denied". I also get a permission denied error if I try to open the config file in read only with a text editor, via `nano -v /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

I'm using the Python 3.3 cartridge. I can't find any way of finding the apache modules directly from python (the list of loaded modules doesn't seem to be passed via the environ argument to the WSGI app object).

Also, trying via php doesn't help. `php -r "phpinfo();"` doesn't give the info - I've grepped in the output for 'apache' and 'mod_', and looked with the naked eye, and there's no sign of any apache module data. Trying `apache_get_modules` also didn't work, the function is undefined.

I was particularly wondering if the mod_setenvif module was available (the `SetEnvIf` command doesn't seem to be working for me..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the currently loaded apache modules by looking at the following file on your gear: /php/usr/shared/etc/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks. Did I miss this in the documentation somewhere (or is it something people with more experience just know)?

Comment: I do not believe it's in the documentation, it's just knowing how cartridges are laid out and knowing where to look for things.